# Numerical stability of Mehod of lines for Wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Hello mathematicians,

I focus on the numerical solution of partial differential equations (PDEs).
Recently, I was studying the numerical stability of method of lines (MOL).

Method of lines transforms a given PDE into the system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs).
The ODEs then can be solved using standard numerical methods (e.g. Runge-Kutta, etc.).

I found this publication: Numerical stability of MOL for PDEs by R. Vichnevetsky: https://scholarship.libraries.rutgers.edu/esploro/outputs/technicalDocumentation/Numerical-stability-of-methods-of-lines/991031549877904646

There are stability conditions for:

- a) parabolic equation 1D (Tab. 1, p. 17)
- b) hyperbolic equation 1D (Tab. 2, p. 21)

**My problem is:**
I would like to derive the stability condition for the 2nd order hyperbolic equation, and I would like to ensure that it is correctly derived.

**Firstly, I review the stability condition for 1st order hyperbolic PDE (from the article above, p. 18):**
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + f\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0
$$

In equation (26) from the article, we have ($c$ are the characteristic values of $f$):
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + c\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0
$$

We apply central differences:
$$
\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]_n \approx \frac{u_{n+1} - u_{n-1}}{2\Delta x}
$$

Thus:
$$
\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial t} \approx -\frac{c}{2\Delta x} (u_{n+1} - u_{n-1})
$$

Spectral function of the right-hand side:
$$
A(\omega) = -\frac{c}{2\Delta x} (e^{j\omega \Delta x} - e^{-j\omega \Delta x})
$$

Because: $e^{j\omega \Delta x} - e^{-j\omega \Delta x} = 2j \sin \phi$, we get:
$$
A(\omega) = -\frac{jc}{\Delta x} \sin (\omega \Delta x)
$$

Numerical stability condition is:
$$
|\Delta t A(\omega)|_{max}  = \left | \frac{c \Delta t}{\Delta x} \sin (\omega \Delta x) \right |_{max} = \frac{c \Delta t}{\Delta x} \leq |S_I|
$$
and is purely-imaginary for all $\omega$.

Note, that $S_I$ is the intersection of the stability boundary of the integration method with the imaginary axis.

**Now, I am trying to derive a similar stability condition for the wave equation -- 2nd order hyperbolic PDE:**

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + \alpha^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0
$$

We apply central differences:
$$
\left[\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right]_n \approx \alpha^2 \left(\frac{u_{n+1} - 2u_n +  u_{n-1}}{\Delta x^2}\right)
$$

Spectral function of the right-hand side:
$$
A(\omega) = \frac{\alpha^2}{\Delta x^2} (-2+  e^{j\omega \Delta x} + e^{-j\omega \Delta x})
$$

Because $e^{j\omega \Delta x} + e^{-j\omega \Delta x} = 2 \cos \omega$, we get:

$$
A(\omega) = \frac{\alpha^2}{\Delta x^2} (-2+2 \cos (\omega \Delta x)) \\
A(\omega) = -\frac{2\alpha^2}{\Delta x^2} (1-\cos (\omega \Delta x))
$$

Because the maximum amplitude of $\cos$ is $\pm1$, then the bracket is $(1-\cos (\omega \Delta x)) = 2$.

Numerical stability condition is:
$$
|\Delta t^2 A(\omega)|_{max}  = \left | \frac{4 \alpha^2 \Delta t^2}{\Delta x^2}\right | \leq |S_R| 
$$
and is real for all values of $\omega$.

Note, that $S_R$ is the intersection of the stability boundary of the integration method with the real axis.

I am modelling the heat equation, so I am using the $\alpha$ parameter, which represents thermal diffusivity (e.g. copper = $11.3e^{-5} m^/s$.

**I would like to kindly ask you: Is this stability condition correct, please?**

Thank you very much in advance. Any help is highly appreciated :-).

Answer (score 1):

Note that you also have a second order derivative in $t$. So to apply a standard numerical method you have to construct a first-order system. To get a small matrix norm or to see eigenvalues easily, distribute the factor equally.
$$
\pmatrix{\hat u_t(ω,t)\\\hat v_t(ω,t)}
=\frac{2α\sin(ωΔx/2)Δt}{Δx}
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{\hat u(ω,t)\\\hat v(ω,t)}
$$
As this gives pairs of eigenvalues of opposite sign, the exact solution is not stable, and thus this can also not be preserved by the numerical method.

Note that what you started with is the Poisson equation, the wave equation has the opposite sign and then above calculations lead again to the imaginary trace of the stability region.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  Ah, I am sorry, you are right, the equation should be:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \alpha^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$

Yes, I understand, that I have to use substitution to get rid of the second derivative in $t$. I am just wondering how you get the formula.. Because if we replace the right-hand side with central finite differences, we will still have:

Comment: Continued: -- we still have:
$$
A(\omega) = \frac{\alpha^2}{\Delta x^2} (-2+  e^{j\omega \Delta x} + e^{-j\omega \Delta x})
$$
And $e^{j\omega \Delta x} + e^{-j\omega \Delta x} = 2 \cos \omega$. 
I do not know how we can get $\sin$ instead of $\cos$.

I have probably a bad sign somewhere, because it seems we need $ e^{j\omega \Delta x} - e^{-j\omega \Delta x} = 2j\sin \phi$.

Comment: $\hat u(ω,t)$ is the Fourier series of the space discretization, the central differences are included, I just added that $(1-\cos(ωΔx))=2\sin^2(ωΔx/2)$ to the eigenvalue you computed, and distributed the resulting square evenly.

Comment: Thank you again. So, can the stability condition be written in this form? 
$$
 \left | \frac{2 \alpha \Delta t}{\Delta x}\right | \leq |S_I|
$$

Comment: I believe you mean the right thing. If it is formally correct depends on the interpretation of the right side. What you mean is the maximum, but using the absolute value on segments usually means their length.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Yes, I meant the maximum, apologize for unclear notation. So now, I can express $\Delta t$ and obtain the condition for the suitable time step size for a given integration method:

$$
\Delta t \leq \frac{|S_I| \Delta x}{2 \alpha}
$$

Comment: Please, does it mean, that for example ode45 (Dormand-Prince 4(5)) formula is unstable? 
When I checked the stability region, it has an intersection with the real axis SR=-3.266, but does not have an intersection with the imaginary axis SI = +/-0j.

Comment: Yes, all explicit RK methods have a limited stability region. Thus the existence of stiff ODE where at sensible tolerances an adaptive solver will loiter around the boundary of the stability region, making small steps even when the solution has converged to an almost constant. Normally one would expect the local step size to be proportional to $\tau^{1/p}$ where $\tau$ is the error tolerance and $p$ the order.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense. I tried to solve the Wave equation (e.g. length L=1 and 10 segments, resulting in dx=0.1) using various ODE solvers. All of them were capable to solve it, just for example the ode15s has the average stepsize 8e-3, while the ode45 has 2.5e-3, that means more than 3-times smaller stepsize in comparison with the ode15s.